# ScrollWindow has Absolutely No Effect

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, winforms-interop

I'm creating a User Control for WinForms and have the need to scroll a section of the control window.

Inexplicably, it appears no ScrollWindow() method is available in WinForms. So I'm trying to use InteropServices to use the Win32 API ScrollWindow() function using variations of the following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
public struct RECT
{
    public int left; 
    public int top; 
    public int right; 
    public int bottom; 

    public RECT(Rectangle rect)
    {
        this.bottom = rect.Bottom;
        this.left = rect.Left;
        this.right = rect.Right;
        this.top = rect.Top;
    }
}

[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern int ScrollWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nXAmount, int nYAmount,
    ref RECT rectScrollRegion, ref RECT rectClip);

void MyScrollFunc(int yAmount)
{
    RECT r = new RECT(ClientRectangle);
    ScrollWindow(Handle, 0, yAmount, ref r, ref r);
}
```

The result is that this code does absolutely nothing. I've tried all sorts of variations of this code, including calling Update() after the scroll (which shouldn't be necessary).

ScrollWindow() is returning 1, which signifies success but it simply has no effect on the content of the control window no matter what I try.

Does anyone know if there's something about a user control that prevents modifying the display this way? I'm testing this on C# Express Edition 2008 on Windows XP.

Comment: Maybe if you describe what needs to be scrolled and where, you'd find out how the pattern works in .NET winforms.

Comment: What kind of content does this UserControl have?  Child controls (windowless or windowed?), background image set via property, a rendering using a `Graphics` object?  Does the control have the DoubleBuffered style?

Comment: @Will: I want my user control to show lines of text and, when a new line is added, I want everything to scroll up and then I can add the new line at the bottom. I know there are many ways to do this in user controls, but they all seem to involve repainting the entire control. Being the silly person I am, I was hoping for something far more efficient.

Comment: @Ben: All contents of the control will be owner drawn. I have DoubleBuffered currently set to false.

Comment: @Jonathan: Does `OnPaint` get called after ScrollWindow?  What about `OnPaintBackground`?  Override these if you haven't already and stick some trace output in both.

Comment: @Jon agreed, premature optimization is silly.  <strike>Now, have you tried setting AutoScroll on your panel to true?</strike> Aw hell, its been a looong time since I've winformed.

Comment: @Ben: It appears the Paint handler is not being called. It behaves as though I'm scrolling the wrong window. (There is no PaintBackground event.)

Comment: @Will: Trying to work out a design for a control that will be efficient is hardly premature. What a silly credo if you apply it that way. AutoScroll works on a completely different principle. The only way to optimize that approach would be to rewrite it.

Comment: @Jonathan: You have a class that derives from `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl`, right?  Override the virtual functions `OnPaint` and `OnPaintBackground`.  Events are for the consumers of your control.

Comment: @Jon unless you waste all your time trying to get a win32 method working in a managed UI control when there is already an easy way to do it.  Something tells me you're new to the managed world.  Honestly, if I were to give you any advice worth anything, it would be to skip over winforms, drop everything you know about UI, and dive headlong into WPF.

Comment: @Will: Yes, WPF is on the list. But I reject the notion that we can't ever try to be efficient if it means rolling your own logic. The fact is there are easy ways to scroll, but not to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks. Those methods are not being called as a result of calling ScrollWindow(). Again, it's as though I'm scrolling the wrong window.

Comment: @Jonathan: you probably *are* scrolling the wrong window. You're passing `this.Handle` to `ScrollWindow`, but that's the handle to the "outer" window of the user control, not to the internal window that actually holds the content. I think you'd have to do more Win32 mojo and get the first (hopefully it's the first) child window's hWnd, and then pass *that* handle to `ScrollWindow`.

Comment: @Jonathan: Which is probably a lot more work than it's worth. I'd like to add to the general chorus here, and mention that it has been possible to create scrollable user controls, and very easily without using the Win32 API, in .Net for 10 years now. Based on your description of what your user control needs to do, I would personally estimate this task at under 1 hour. I'm only saying this to stress the fact that you will have a *much* easier time achieving what you want without the Win32 API.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: I will explore the child window issue--I've been wondering about something like that. As far as the "general chorus", no one has suggested a method to accomplish what I want that makes the least bit of sense to me. And I know from past experience that most people seem to shy away from digging a little deeper to make something efficient, which is exactly the goal here.

Comment: @Jonathan: you are correct that using `AutoScroll` for this would be inefficient IFF your "virtual" window is gigantic compared to the size of the viewable "port". If I had this problem, I would write my own user control with logic to render just the visible portion of my data (much like how any implementation of a grid view works [or *should* work]). But this solution wouldn't involve the `AutoScroll` property *or* the call to `ScrollWindow`.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Writing my own user control with logic to render just the visible portion of my data is **exactly** what I'm trying to do. If I don't use `ScrollWindow()`, Then each time a line is added, I must redraw the entire control. And what do I get for this trade off of inefficiency? Not a thing. Sounds lame. Must just be me.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Also, I tried using `GetWindow(Handle, GW_CHILD)`, which returned 0. This suggests the window I'm working with has no child windows.

Comment: @Jonathan: you can do what you're trying to do *without* calling `ScrollWindow`. If you implement this as a double-buffered control (by which I mean something that has nothing to do with the control's `DoubleBuffered` property, which doesn't do what you think it does), then you do your raw drawing onto one hidden buffer (a `Bitmap'), and when complete you copy the entire buffer onto a second hidden buffer and call Refresh on your control. In the control's Paint event, you copy the second hidden buffer onto the visible surface (aka you use the DrawImage method of the Graphics object passed ...

Comment: ... to the Paint event). This double-buffered approach is critical to avoid flicker, but it also has this beneficial property: before you begin re-drawing the first buffer, the second buffer is always an exact copy of the first. So, in a manner akin to using `ScrollWindow`, you can just copy most of the second buffer into the first, offset upwards by the height of one line of text. Then you just draw the new line at the bottom.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Where'd the comment about the `DoubleBuffered` property not doing what I think it does, come from? I know exactly what the property does! At any rate, I can see this is moving in the direction of less efficient code when I want to move the opposite direction.

Comment: However, having written approximately 1 million C# user controls like this in the last 10 years, I can guarantee that your emphasis on efficiency here is misplaced. Drawing text and lines takes virtually no time at all in .Net, so you're not really going to gain much performance at all by using `ScrollWindow`. And that's in Windows - FYI, I recently completed a similar user-control-type thing for Blackberry, and even though I was using Java on their crappy alleged smartphones, text- and line-rendering was so fast that efficiency here was completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Jonathan: then you know that the `DoubleBuffered` property of a user control is only relevant if the control contains other controls (buttons, text boxes etc.)?

Comment: @MusiGenesis: As far as the technique you described, yes, it would work. But I'm now juggling three bitmaps if you include the screen. I'll have to explore options like this if I can't get `ScrollWindow()` to work. But, I'm sorry, I still want to answer the question why `ScrollWindow()` *won't* work.

Comment: @Jonathan: I'm pretty sure an auto-scrollable control consists of more than one window, where the content is initially drawn on a child window and then rendered to the outer parent window. Use `GetWindow` (Win32 API - yay!) to get a handle to the correct child window, and then `ScrollWindow` might work the way you want.

Comment: @Jonathan: also, regarding the double-buffered technique I described, it depends on what you mean by "efficiency", exactly. It's more efficient in terms of the time it takes to render each frame, but it achieves this efficiency at the cost of greater memory consumption. Like everything, it's an engineering trade-off.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: I'm going to disagree with you on both counts. First, drawing many lines of text does take time, particularly if there are many updates in a short period of time. Second, the `DoubleBuffered` property *IS* relevant for owner drawn controls. I've used it before to eliminate flicker. Beyond that, I can work around this if I can't use `ScrollWindow()`. But I consider not understanding why it won't work a poor excuse for working around it.

Comment: @MusicGenesis: What is the trade off for using `ScrollWindow()`? What would I lose if I was able to figure out how to make it work, besides a little more coding?

Comment: @MusicGenesis: Perhaps you missed my reply above. I did use `GetWindow()` and it returned 0. However, I'm not using `AutoScroll` and so I don't get your point there.

Comment: If you can make it work, then you've lost nothing at all. :) You might want to try `ScrollWindowEx`, however, since you can apparently call it in a way that will scroll all *child* windows within the passed rectangle, so perhaps that would make your code work as is.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787593(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read your comment about GetWindow. I'm wrong again, which happens from time to time. :)

Comment: @MusiGenesis: I appreciate you sticking with me this long. I know I can be a pain. :) The bottom line is I can't believe Controls don't have a ScrollWindow() method, and it seems like there should be someway to perform this simple task. I've come up empty on Google. I may look at `ScrollWindowEx` but seriously doubt it will work where `ScrollWindow` won't.

Comment: @Jonathan: yeah, I only suggested ScrollWindowEx before I realized that you didn't have any child windows. I stuck with you because I (and the other commenters) didn't originally correctly understand what you were asking and why. I've been on the other side of that at StackOverflow, so I know how much it makes me want to hit somebody with a fish. :)

Comment: As far as there being no ScrollWindow method on controls, you're lucky you can even still call the Win32 API from C#!  :)

Comment: @Jonathan: does it work if you pass `Null` for the two `RECT` parameters? Some of the samples I found online do that.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Well, I tried every variation using two different RECT structures and setting them both to the full client rectangle so I don't think that's it. But, to be honest, I'm not sure how to pass null so it will compile. Do I need to change the declaration to specify `IntPtr` arguments?

Comment: Yeah, change the declaration to IntPtr and try passing Null - maybe that will work. Also, try something simple like a PictureBox with an image pre-loaded, and see if the call scrolls the image like you would expect. There might be some windows weirdness going on with user controls, although I use `BitBlt` etc. inside user controls all the time.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: YES! Passing NULL for both rects causes the code to produce the expected results. I don't yet understand what was wrong with my rects before but at least I have something to play with. Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out `ScrollWindow()` works just fine. I had copied some code from the Web that had the members of the `RECT` structure out of order. Thanks to MusiGenesis for the tip that got me looking in the right place (I just assumed the code I copied was correct--my mistake.)

Yes, I do like to write efficient code sometimes and it usually means I butt heads in places like SO by people who think I should just use whatever's on the shelf. Different people like to approach software development in different ways, and I think that's okay.

If anyone's curious, I was writing a multi-line status control. I wanted it to be fast because my app can send many messages to the control in a short period of time. An article about the control, along with the final source code has been posted at http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/controls/a-scrolling-status-control.

Answer (score 3):

As `Will` pointed out in a comment, you can easily make your user control scrollable by setting its `AutoScroll` property - there is no need tap the Win32 API to achieve this functionality.

If you really want to use the API, at least use `ScrollWindowEx` instead of `ScrollWindow`.

**Update:**  Since I randomly guessed this, the answer is:

Pass `Null` for the two `RECT` parameters.

Comment: The `AutoScroll` property is all very nice and well. It's just that it doesn't do what I'm trying to do.